# Get notification of new version of app available in Google Play store

Tags: android, notifications, version, google-play

I am making new version of my app and i have uploaded it on android market now i want my users to get notification that new version of app is available.I don't know how to do this.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Push notifications to notify users using C2DM.. https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment I believe there is no mechanism to handle that for you automatically (android market notifying an app).
What you can do, since you yourself releases the application to the market, is have another server (your own) notified or updated that an update is available. That server can then do push notifications to your app. 
You can use Android's c2dm push, or implement your own using your gateway of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 alternatives -

1. Push - You can send a push notification to all the users of your application that there is an upgrade available. (But it will require work and resources in terms of coding and server).
   You can find a good tutorial for doing Push here 
   http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

2
. Pull - Do a asynctask in your Android app, such that, whenever the app is opened, it checks asynchronously if there are any upgrades (by having a version code in a URL), and show a dialog to the user if the version code is greater than what it is in the device. This is a easier approach.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about pull .I mean with some sample code

Comment: Simple..Do a http get using http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-get-request-with-httpclient    The URL will be a text file on your server containing the version code like 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Using the above code, you get the version code (which is the upgraded version), and check if its greater than your current version, and then pop a dialog to the user that a upgrade is available.

Comment: I use the http code mentioned by you but can you please help me in how to make text file containig version code and how will it check the version of app..